# Is will_paginate query executed more than once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, rails-activerecord

Let's say I have an ActiveRecord query which has 1 million records as result and I'm using WillPaginate to (of course) paginate this result. 
So, my doubt is:
All these 1 million records are stored somehow in memory or the will_paginate query gets executed again to retrieve more and more records ?

I hope I'm being clear :)

Comment: nope, will paginate uses limits and offsets to fetch only the records you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it won't repeatedly grab all 1 million records. The queries look something like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... LIMIT X OFFSET Y
```

...where `X` is the maximum per page, and `Y` is the number of records to skip from the top of the stack, as determined by `X * (current_page - 1)`.

Comment: Thanks @Chris, that's exactly the console output. I should have checked it before asking :)

Answer (score 1):

Will_paginate will run separate queries to populate the data and will not fetch all the data at once. You can check how will paginate works in the terminal also. Lets say you are using rails default webrick server. Then in your terminal you will see the sql queries made by will_paginate like so:

```
Processing by InvoicesController#index as HTML


Invoice Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "invoices".* FROM "invoices" ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```